# Se borra mi demas informacion de mi estado en react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ckeditor

Comento, yo estoy usando CKEditor 4 para publicar post en mi pagina, ahora, la informacion que lleban estas publicaciones esta de la siguiente forma:

```
const [post, setPost] = useState({
    titulo: '',
    descripcion: '',
    body: ''
});
```

Ahora, para facilitarme las cosas uso la siguiente funcion la cual cambia la informacion

```
const changeData = (name, value) => {
    setPost({ ...post, [name]: value })
    setSalirSinGuardar(true)
}
```

Aqui es donde se cambia toda la informacion, ahora mi problema surge ya que cuando mando la inforamcion del body

```
//Input que se utiliza para insertar informacion en titulo
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="title">Titulo de la publicacion</label>
    <input className="form-control" name="nombre" type="text" value={post.nombre} onChange={(e)=> changeData(e.target.name, e.target.value)}/>
</div>

<CKEditor
    initData={post.body}
    onChange={(event) => {
        changeData('body', event.editor.getData())
    }}
    style={{ height:'100%' }}
/>
```

Este no solo cambia la informacion del body sino que le quita la informacion al titulo y a la descripcion, entonces no se muy bien que es lo que esta pasando

Consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui en la imagen el primer change data, fue cuando inserte la palabra titulo para luego insertar unicamente la letra a en CKEditor y como se puede apreciar, elimina la informacion de titulo y descripcion pero si vuelvo a escribir algo en titulo y descripcion estos no se borran y permanecen, entonces no se que puede estar provocando esto, alguien tiene una idea? estoy setenado mal la informacion y es por eso que pasa?

Comment: De dónde sale la información del título? En qué otros lugares se llama a `setPost()`

Comment: Unicamente en ese lugar en esa funcion

Comment: Pero entonces como seteas el título luego de setear body?

Comment: Usando la misma funcion changeData, le mando el nombre o la key y luego el valor para que lo setee, esto tanto para la descripcion como para el titulo

Comment: Entonces si llamas a `setPost()` para el titulo y descripcion, por favor agrega ese código tambien

Answer (score 0):

Trata pasar un callback al `setPost`.

```js
const changeData = (name, value) => {
    setPost(prev => { ...prev, [name]: value })
    setSalirSinGuardar(true)
}
```

El callback accede directamente al estado anterior de ese `useState`. No veo nada en tu código que pueda borrar el estado anterior del `post`.

En tu consola veo que estás haciendo un `console.log` de un `useEffect` pero no veo ese `useEffect` en el código que compartiste en tu pregunta. Porque veo que ese `useEffect` también se ejecuta cuando cambias el `post`. Si la solución que te di no te funciona, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y compartas el código del `useEffect`.